# Preselect a default process in SAS Stored Process Web Application

Tags: sas

If you load the SAS Stored Process Web Application in your browser with  some standard parameters *`_action=index,form,properties,execute,newwindow`* you get an banner on top, an treeindex on the left and the empty frame window on the right.

I want to load the page with a default stored process given as parameter, so user can see something in the framewindow on first load.

You can add *`&_program=...`* in the Url to give a process as parameter which will be processed, but this only works if you remove the index in the action-parameters which will remove the index-tree from the page.

So, is there a possibilty to load a default process and also keep the indextree? I can not change the source code, so it has to work only with url-Parameters.

[image]

If you add *`&_program=...`* with a path to a stored process in the url, nothing changes. If you remove parameter index from _action then, it shows the process result, but removes the indextree

So simply said, i am looking for a way to run a specific process in this window, without klicking it in the index-tree, but with url-Parameters...
If this is not possible, i will accept it and live with it, but please no guesses...

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to achieve? I didn't know there was a default stored process in Web Application. The parameters will only apply to an actual stored process, so you shouldn't get an empty right frame. If you don't want the banner, you will hide the log off and change user links on top.

Comment: Hm, not sure what you dont understand, dont know how to explain this better to you. There is always an empty frame on first load with standard parameters. I dont care about the banner. I am talkng about the initial page, there can not be something in the right frame window, because you did not select a process at the time. But i want a default STP result in the right window, which i provide via parameter.

Comment: @Vasilij Nevlev added image for better explanation

Comment: You want the empty frame on the right to show the result of running the stored process (with the tree on the left)?  Or do you want to frame on the right to show the prompts for the stored process?

Comment: @quentin:the result of a specific process. But with selecting the running process via url, not by clicking in the tree. So i give somebody an url, and he opens it, he already sees the this page with a result of one specififc process (a simple proces without prompt which just puts some html output there) in the right frame window. But not sure if this is possible at all without changing the service source code...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible but if u find a way, please post it. It would be nice to have. I think the _action parameter is a hierarchical list which results in only one item from that list being done when the URL is clicked. What you are describing would be (I think) _action=index and _action=execute both being done. Would be nice, for example to have the right frame show a title page or other simple menu, while still leaving the left frame index for navigation. You might try asking on communities.sas.com aa well.

Comment: @quentin: For now i builded a workaround, loading a STP as info/FAQ-site with &_program and &_action=execute without tree-index, and this info page has included a link to page with tree-index and empty right-frame. Not exactly what i wanted, but at least something we can work it. i hope someone else can tell me if there is a more direct way to do this in just on step without an extra link...

Comment: kl78, what version of SAS you are on? Sorry, I didn't have access to SAS over the last several days. I don't think I can resolve your problem exactly, but I will put it in the answer exactly why you it can't be resolved.

Comment: @ Vasilij Nevlev: Our customers use 9.3. . I already guessed that it is not possible they way i wanted and builded a workaround. You could build this with only some small changes in Application server code, but i can not use this because of some administration restrictions at our customers server.  But if you have additional information, please post them...